# Is process name same as package name in android?

Tags: android, process, task, activity-manager

By process I mean what we provide in `android:process` and by package I mean package in

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.osg.appkiller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

More details [Processes and Threads - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

I wanted to get application names of all running apps. So this is what I did after looking at various sources (and it works).

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
        CharSequence appName = null;
        try {
            appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(processInfo.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Application info not found for process : " + processInfo.processName,e);
        }
    }
```

If you see Documentation for PackageManager.getApplicationInfo

```
ApplicationInfo android.content.pm.PackageManager.getApplicationInfo(String packageName, int flags) throws NameNotFoundException
```

but I am passing

```
processInfo.processName
```

where processName is name of process running. So we are basically using process name as package name  to get application info.

1. First of all is this approach correct ?
2. Secondly is it true that if we do not provide process for activities/services etc new process is created with same name as that of package name  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default android takes the package name as the process name. But if you define process property in application tag in manifest file `android:process="com.example.newprocessname"` then the application will run with this name "com.example.newprocessname".

As for your questions,

- 1-> In this case your application name is same as the default package name, that's why it is working. Try changing the process name. It'll not work.
- 2-> That's true. It is by default. Refer to "android:process" in the following link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Hope this answers your question!